# algorithm to determine whether a value is within a range of a multiple

Tags: python, algorithm

Algorithm question:

Let's say I want to determine whether a value is within a range (eg 2) of a tens multiple -- so, 8-12, 18-22, 28-32, etc.

My current solution is to add the range to the value, mod by 10, then re-subtract the range -- thus leaving me with something from -2 to 8 -- and then check whether the absolute value is less than the desired range.

```
value = 38
range = 2
cycle = 10

tweaked_mod = ((value + range) % cycle) - range
# tweaked_mod = -2
within_range = (abs(tweaked_mod) <= range)
# within_range = True
```

versus:

```
value = 37
range = 2
cycle = 10

tweaked_mod = ((value + range) % cycle) - range
# tweaked_mod = 7
within_range = (abs(tweaked_mod) <= range)
# within_range = False
```

It works, but it's awkward.

Am I missing a more intuitive / succinct algorithm here?

Comment: Why can't you just take value mod 10 and then check whether the answer is < range if < 5 and > 10-range if > 5.

Comment: @Abhishek -- I'm tentatively (locally) working with an algorithm that's essentially doing that -- and agreed, it's ultimately clearer to explain / comment. My reasoning for still posting this topic, though, was just in case I was missing some deeper / more powerful concept that accomplished the same thing, either generically or in Python specifically.

Comment: Also, feel free to post your suggestion as an answer -- if that remains the clearest approach, then I'd like to flag it as the chosen answer.

Comment: sorry I'm not aware of any built-in function in Python that would do this for you cleanly. Thanks for the flag offer, but people have already posted very good answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find this solution easier to understand:

```
remainder = (value % cycle)
(remainder <= range) || (cycle - remainder) <= range
```

Basically I find the remainder of the `value` I search for in respect of the modulo (`cycle`) and then check if it is within the expected range.

**Alternative:**

An alternative solution (doing essentially the same) will be:

```
remainder = (value % cycle)
min(remainder, cycle - remainder) <= range
```

You are free to choose whichever of the two solutions you like better.

**NOTE** This algorithm works verbatim if `range` < `cycle`. In the other cases answer is always true.

Comment: The one I came up with was (remainder <= range) || (remainder >= (cycle-range)). For a cycle of 10 and a range of 2, it will create the conditional remainder <= 2 || remainder >= 8 && remainder < 10. With the remainder < 10 being implied through the modulus operation.

Comment: Much obliged. I like the approach a lot. Fewer calculations, thus less to comment / maintain.

Comment: Also -- question (and thus answer) has been commented in my code for reference, so likely more hits / votes will come in the future.